# How to use a piechart(jFreechart) with database values

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to populate a piechart with data from database using Jfreechart, how to do this?

I was using a chart with static and predetermined values.
Any help will be appreciated and thank you!!

Comment: For additional guidance, please edit your question to include a [mcve], for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24762078/230513) or [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26942183/230513).

Comment: It looks like you want `JDBCPieDataset` like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13582523/261156).

Comment: See also [*Visualize Your Oracle Database Data with JFreeChart*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/marx-jchart-085298.html).